# Errors when deploying Tomcat7 webapp

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss, tomcat7, resteasy

I'm trying to deploy a simple Resteasy application using Java7 to Tomcat7.

I get these errors on startup:

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/scannotation/AnnotationDB$CrossReferenceException

SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
java.lang.NullPointerException

I'm using apache maven for the dependencies which is retrieving from 
`<repository>
   <id>jboss</id>
   <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
 </repository>`

The web.xml can be found at http://pastebin.com/Nsuh71ES.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining the maven cache, the jboss resteasy library hadn't been fully downloaded.
The problem was due to the fact that org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap could not be accessed